# Nativescript RadListView scrollOffset is always 0

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am using the RadListView plugin in a Nativescript-vue project. I created a file based on this playground approach to get it running with vue - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=i28vZu&v=4.

The problem I am having is that the scrolloffset is always 0 in the scroll event.  I dont know if this is an issue with vuejs or the plugin in general.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: unable to find scroll event in playground demo

Comment: I posted that link to show how radlistview looks running in nativescriot-vue when I use the component and add the scrolled event ie <RadListView @scrolled="onScrolled" > I console log out the event.scrollOffset in onScrolled callback and it is always 0

Comment: please update the playground link with this/.

Comment: here is the updated link with the scroll event if you check the log it is always zero as you are scrolling https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=i28vZu&v=12